# Check if string have uppercase, lowercase and number

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I want to check if my string have Uppercase & LowerCase & Number

```
string myString = "Hello123";

if (myString haveUppercase && myString haveLowerCase && myString haveNumber)
{
    this.hide();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error!");
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use `char`'s methods with `LINQ`:

```
if (myString.Any(char.IsUpper) &&
    myString.Any(char.IsLower) &&
    myString.Any(char.IsDigit))
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if (myString.Any(ch => char.IsUpper(ch) &&
    myString.Any(ch => char.IsLower(ch) &&
    myString.Any(ch => char.IsDigit(ch))
    { 
      this.hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!");
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of completess, the *classic*, non-LINQ way to achieve this:

```
public static bool HasUpperLowerDigit(string text)
{
    bool hasUpper = false; bool hasLower = false; bool hasDigit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length && !(hasUpper && hasLower && hasDigit); i++)
    {
        char c = text[i];
        if (!hasUpper) hasUpper = char.IsUpper(c);
        if (!hasLower) hasLower = char.IsLower(c);
        if (!hasDigit) hasDigit = char.IsDigit(c);
    }
    return hasUpper && hasLower && hasDigit;
}
```

It is more efficient because it loops every character only once whereas the LINQ approaches need three enumerations.

Answer (score 7):

How about?

```
if(myString.Any(char.IsLower) && myString.Any(char.IsUpper) && myString.Any(char.IsDigit))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use Extension Method for Alphanumeric as group like below

> (Also we can use different Extension method for Small Letters, Capital
>   Letters and Numbers separately if we need)

```
static class StringExtension
{

    public static bool IsAlphaNumeric(this string strToCheck)
    {
        Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,]*$");
        return rg.IsMatch(strToCheck);

    }

 }
```

We can use the above Extension Method like below :

```
 {

 string strValue = "vasanth";

 strValue.IsAlphaNumeric();  //return true

 string strValue1 = "vasanth!";

 strValue.IsAlphaNumeric();  //return false

  }
```

Comment: Some languages e.g. chinese don't differentiate between upper and lower case as they're ideographs, if that matters to your software

Answer (score 0):

#region check if there's upper case letter

```
        string Mystring = "SimpleWordforExAmple";
        char[] chars;
        char ch;
        int length = Mystring.Length;
        int cnt;
        int totalcntupper = 0;

        chars = Mystring.ToCharArray(0, length);

        Console.WriteLine("Sample words with capital letters : {0} ", Mystring);
        for (cnt = 0; cnt < length;cnt ++)
        {
            ch = chars[cnt];


            if (char.IsUpper(ch))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Capital letter : #{0}", ch);
                totalcntupper++;

            }


        }

        Console.WriteLine("Count of capital letter(s) : # {0}", totalcntupper);
        Console.ReadLine();








        #endregion
```

i hope you got an idea. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do some strong password validation.
While there are many ways to skin this cat, I prefer to wrap such code into reusable extension methods that make it trivial to do going forward.  When using extension methods, you can also avoid RegEx as it is slower than a direct character check.  I like using the extensions in the Extensions.cs NuGet package.  It makes this check as simple as:

1. Add the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extensions.cs package to your project.
2. Add "`using Extensions;`" to the top of your code.

Your example code would become as simple as:

```
string myString = "Hello123";

//if (myString haveUppercase && myString haveLowerCase && myString haveNumber)
if (myString.IsStrong(true, true, true, false))
//If you wanted to allow special characters and require 3 of the 4 it would simply be:
if (myString.IsStrong(3))
{
    this.hide();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error!");
}
```